# Defining new field in JSON Schema for creating 2 view of an object

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I am using JSON Schema for validating and storing data in mongodb, I want to define new key value pair like "required" to have 2 view of an object, one is detailed and another is custom.
First can I write a schema like this or I can just use standard key values?

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Product set",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "title": "Product",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "description": "The unique identifier for a product",
            "type": "number"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "price": {
            "type": "number",
            "minimum": 0,
            "exclusiveMinimum": true
        }
    },
    "required": ["id", "name", "price"]
    "customViewField" : ["name", "price"]
  }
}
```

Is there any parser that do this for me ? (I want to have 2 getter for one object detailed and custom )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unknown keywords in JSON Schema are ignored, so your schema will still be perfectly functional, and all tools should support it.  The new functionality/keywords can just be added to whatever tools you need.

If you're making a custom extension, it would be best-practice to *document* your extensions in a meta-schema (which extends from `http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#`) and reference that in `$schema`.